# How to compile Shrew VPN Xubuntu 12.10 with cmake?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, vpn

I am trying to install Shrew VPN Xubuntu 12.10 and can not compile with `cmake`. Here is the error I am receiving:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DQTGUI=YES -DETCDIR=/etc -DNATT=YES
-- Using install prefix /usr/local ...
-- Using etc path /etc ...
-- Using lib path /usr/local/lib ...
-- Using man path /usr/local/man ...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:196 (message):
Unable to locate openssl crypto include files


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am using the latest stable release of shrew VPN.

Comment: I have tried this few months ago on 12.04 and there was the same result. A needed library was missing and could not find it. Why don't you install it from software center?

Comment: I can not find it within the software center. Is there a downloaded .deb package somehwere?

Comment: I need shrew in particular because i need to be able to load PCF files.

Comment: You need `libssl-dev`: that will ensure a successful build. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 3):

Shrew vpn used to be in the repositories under the name [ike](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ike), so on 12.04 you could install it very simply with `sudo apt-get install ike`; however this is not possible on 12.10, so one solution would be to compile it.

For compilation you will need the [stable release](http://www.shrew.net/download/ike/ike-2.1.7-release.tgz) code and the necessary dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libaudio-dev libcups2-dev
```

Note: this will build the command-line client, but not the gui unless you have the `qt-dev` and toolkit files installed (it requires qt 3.3 or above, but has not been tested with qt4; see the readme with the download for further information).

Now, the configuring with `cmake` should be fine, and you can specify all the custom options that I see you require when you run it.

This was the successful completion of the configure with the above dependencies installed:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mike/src/ike
```

Without `libssl-dev` installed I get exactly the error you received:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:196 (message):
Unable to locate openssl crypto include files
```

You can use install and use `checkinstall` to install the compiled program, or you may have other plans.

Comment: good one Mik...